# Getting error using cor() in For loop in R for list of csv files

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, variance

I have a list of csv files that I'm iterating through

```
corr <- function(directory) {
        filename <- list.files(directory)
        x <- paste(directory, "/", sep="")
        monitor_list <- paste(x, filename, sep="")
        completeLocations <- NULL
        corrData <- NULL
```

I'm trying to use cor() to generate another data frame that just has the cor values for 2 columns in each csv file.

```
  for (monitor in monitor_list) {
            locationInfo <- read.csv(monitor)
            corrData <- rbind(corrData, cor(locationInfo$sulfate, locationInfo$nitrate, use = "complete.obs"))
            completeLocations <- rbind(completeLocations, sum(complete.cases(locationInfo)))


        }
```

And it throws this error

> Error in cor(locationInfo$sulfate, locationInfo$nitrate, use =
>   "complete.obs") :    no complete element pairs

I know this can be done because when I run the exact same thing outside of the loop, it return the correlation for the last csv file in the list.

```
 print(cor(locationInfo$sulfate, locationInfo$nitrate, use = "complete.obs"))
```

I'm relatively new to R and I think I'm missing something inside of the loop, I'm just not sure what it is...

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to replicate that error

```
dd<-data.frame(x=c(1:10, rep(NA,10)), y=c(rep(NA, 10), 1:10))
cor(dd$x, dd$y, use="complete.obs")
```

So it seems likely that either all of your nitrate and sulfate values are 'NA' or that when one is not 'NA', the other is always 'NA'. So check that your `locationInfo` data.frame looks the way you expect.

Comment: You are right, there are a few values for cor that return NA. I changed the use parameter to `use = "na.or.complete"` and it worked.

Comment: @KeonCummings Well, keep in mind that just "not returning an error" isn't the same as "gave you the results you needed." If you thought complete.obs should have worked and it didn't there's something wrong with your data.

Comment: I got the results I needed, using this `corrData <- data.frame(rbind(corrData, cor(locationInfo$sulfate, locationInfo$nitrate, use = "na.or.complete")))' instead of this `corrData <- rbind(corrData, cor(locationInfo$sulfate, locationInfo$nitrate, use = "complete.obs"))`